# How to disable "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY" in sql server

Tags: sql-server, group-by, aggregation, sql-mode

I know that in mysql we can disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY to do aggregations in relation to other fields than the selected ones. But in sql server i don't know how.

Here is the query i tried :

```
select Arrival_Date, sum(Rate) 
from Stay
Group by month(Arrival_Date)
```

i got the followed error:

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Column 'Stay.Arr_Date' is invalid in the select list because it is not 
contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Comment: have you found any solution to this? I've having the same problem. Will post an answer if I find one.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to try so show each date that is part of the aggregated group. I think you wanted:

```
select 
    Month = month(Arrival_Date), 
    Total = sum(Rate) 
from 
    Stay
group by 
    month(Arrival_Date)
```